# Collapsing toolbar issue with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in layout, below that I have placed a  `RecyclerView`. it works perfect and the parallax effects comes smoothly when the `RecyclerView` scrolls, but the issue, is suppose if the `RecyclerView` has less items and there is nothing to scroll, still it scolls and an empty space shows at the bottom. what my requirment is it shouldn't scroll if the `RecyclerView` can accomodate all the views in the visible screen, is there any way to do this ?

**layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/container_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/bg_color"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:minHeight="250dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ToggleButton
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_xs"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:textOff=""
                        android:textOn=""/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```